# Set Checked Property of checkbox by Ternary Operator In Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

In my component I have a checkbox like

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
  <input id="approved" name="approval" type="checkbox" (change)="clickEvent($event)" 
    [checked]="Model.IsApproved =='Yes'?true:false">
    <label for="approved">Approved /label>
 </div>
```

IsApproved  is a property of type string in my client side model , it contain either Yes or No.

I want to set it as checked if IsApproved  is Yes otherwise Unchecked .

I tried below Combination

```
[checked]="IsApproved ===Yes?'true':'false'"

[checked]="IsApproved ==Yes?'true':'false'"

[checked]="IsApproved =='Yes'?true:false"

[checked]="{{IsApproved ===Yes?'true':'false'}}"
```

But Nothing seems to work here , is it possible with ternary operator?

Comment: `[checked]="Model.IsApproved.toLowerCase() === 'yes' ? true : false"` is the correct syntax. Check if you can print it with `{{ Model.IsApproved }}` to see the value.

Comment: Try creating a function in component which handles the ternary operator because that's how it's easy I will try to work your sample and post the code soon

Comment: If you put [checked]="Model.IsApproved.toLowerCase() === 'yes' it will return true or false you don't need ternary operation at all

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gq9efu) in order to visualize the answer.

As already said in the comments `[checked]="Model.IsApproved === 'Yes' ? true : false"` is the correct syntax. Seems like your `Model.IsApproved` is not set properly. I set this using `[(ngModel)]` inside an `input` with `type="text"`:

Component:

```
Model = {
    IsApproved: ''
};
```

View:

```
<input type="text" name="approved" [(ngModel)]="Model.IsApproved">

<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
  <input id="approved" name="approval" type="checkbox" (change)="clickEvent($event)" [checked]="Model.IsApproved === 'Yes' ? true : false">
  <label for="approved">Approved</label>
</div>
```

Enter `Yes` in the above input and see it working. Good luck!

Comment: Did the same as this , but still . I don't know what I am missing here

Comment: Please verify the value of `Model.IsApproved` as said in the comments above. Print `{{ Model.IsApproved }}` or `{{ Model.IsApproved | json}}` to see what kind of value it actually contains. If you do not get any result try `{{ Model | json}}`.

Comment: In this case `<input id="approved" name="approval" type="checkbox" (change)="clickEvent($event)" [checked]="Model.IsApproved === 'Yes' ? true : false">` should work. Have you opened up the browser console and looked if another error occurs? If not: maybe you put it inside a `*ngIf` or do something curios inside the `clickEvent`?

Answer (score 1):

### Just use this

```
[checked]="Model.IsApproved =='Yes'"
```

### Still not working ?

You can troubleshoot your problem with -

1. Are you getting any undefined error ? If not then go to next steps else check for the error.
2. Is `Model` is the object you want to refer ?
3. Is property `IsApproved` name is right ?
4. Is property `IsApproved` have the value "Yes" or "No"
5. Check for the case sensitive value. Is it `Yes` or `yes` or `YES`.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

TS

```
public isChecked:boolean
```

Based on condition assign true or false

HTML

```
<label>Checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" />
```

Comment: I asked for ternary operation , not property

Comment: Ternary operator : Property(true/false) ? (true) Do stuff : (false) Do stuff   Example : labelName == "Stackflow" ? "right" : "wrong".If you have multiple conditions (labelName == "Stackflow" ? "right" : "(labelName == "Stack" ?("Only Stack"):("Only Flow")")

Comment: **Property(true/false) ? (true) Do stuff : (false) Do stuff**   Example : **labelName == "Stackflow" ? "right" : "wrong"**.

Answer (score 0):

If you put

```
[checked]="Model.IsApproved.toLowerCase() === 'yes'
```

it will return true or false you don't need ternary operation at all